# How to assign the content to center?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The webpage is designed using the bootstrap. May I know how to assign the content to the center? I have tried to change mx-auto to mt-5, it work for some pictures but not for all.

Below is the coding

```
<div class="mx-auto container d-flex" style="min-height: 500px;">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center" style="flex: 1;">
    <img style="max-width: 80%;" src="{{ asset('upload/artworks/' . $artwork->image_url) }}" 
/>
</div>
<div style="flex: 1;">
    <div class="h-75">
        <div class="mb-5">
            <h2 class="display-5 mb-4">
                {{ $artwork->name }}
            </h2>
            <p class="text-muted">
                {{ $artwork->description }}
            </p>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it the ``<img/>`` you are trying to center ?

Comment: @HugoBp image and the right side content , as you can see, it is very near the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are looking for both the image and content columns to vertically center their content.

The bootstrap class `align-items-center` is what you need here. See example below using your original markup.

EDIT:
Updated to support larger images using `img-fluid` and `gap-5` classes

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="mx-auto container d-flex align-items-center gap-5" style="min-height: 500px;">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center" style="flex: 1;">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x1000" class="img-fluid"
/>
</div>
<div style="flex: 1;">
    <div class="h-75">
        <div class="mb-5">
            <h2 class="display-5 mb-4">
                {{ $artwork->name }}
            </h2>
            <p class="text-muted">
                {{ $artwork->description }}
            </p>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah I'm looking for both the image and content columns to vertically center in the page. I have tried using your method, however the design on the content column is spoiled when insert bigger size of image.

Comment: @fallenhamster I have updated my snippet to support a much larger image. If this does not solve your issue please provide some more detail

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, probably you can try justify-content-between.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).